# Why does the List<? extends Foo> not accept an object of the Foo class?

Tags: java

I tried to add an object of the class `Foo` to a `List<? extends Foo>`, but the code does not compile.

```
final Foo[] array = new Foo[] {new Foo()};
final List<? extends Foo> list = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
for (final Foo foo : array)
{
     // The List<? extends Foo> does not accept the foo object.
     list.add(foo);
}
```

Here is the question again: why is that the case? That doesn't make any sense, does it? I just want a `List` that can contain objects who extend the `Foo` class.

Comment: Not clear what you want to do here. What is the context of this code, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This example is neither complete nor verifiable, so there's not much we can do for you. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: Alright. Now, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: "I just want to know how to fix some annoying behaviour" - Which is...?

Comment: @ToxicTV You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: I still can't get this to run or produce an error similar to what you describe. We're being left to guess what `Event` is, which is probably a decent chunk of the problem.

Comment: Alright, something else you need?

Comment: Possibly see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2891664

Comment: getEventQueue signature?

Comment: It is not possible to add to a List<? extends SomeClass>. I’m not entirely sure but you might need a generic method.

Comment: The problem is that you can't add objects to a `List<? extends Blah>`, so people are asking for an MCVE because we don't know how you should change your code. All we can say is "this doesn't work", which you already know.

Comment: @Toxic *surprised how quickly someone downvotes a question*? Quickly downvoting is one of the *strengths* of this community in order to keep the quality (clear, answerable, future usefulness, etc) of questions high.

Comment: Well, I guess your right about that. I just can't stand critique.

Comment: @Bohemian The problem that I just have with down voting is simple: you edit a question, but people already are unable to find it, because it has been down voted and you can only post a new question every 24 hours. This sucks.

Comment: I get downvoted questions in my feed all the time. Personally, I check them out a lot to see if I want to place a close vote on it. If I decide that it doesn't need to be closed, I'll often stick around and help the asker. So I don't think downvotes preclude you from getting answers.

Comment: And there is a 24 hours threshold, because... well, uhm. Maybe, because you want to make my life harder than it already is? I know the answer to this question. It's called spam. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what `List<? extends Event>` actually *means*. It doesn't mean "I can add any subclass of `Event` to this list". That's simply what a `List<Event>` is, since subclasses can be upcast to `Event`. `List<? extends Event>` says "there is some subclass of `Event` which restricts this type". So if `foo` has type `List<? extends Event>`, then `foo` could feasibly be a `List<Event>`, but it could also be a `List<SomeSpecificTypeOfEvent>`, in which case you aren't allowed to add things that *aren't* `SomeSpecificTypeOfEvent` to it. I think what you want is simply `List<Event>`; the wildcard is overkill here and is not necessary.

Further reading on variance annotations (`extends` and `super`): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

**Edit**: As Johannes Kuhn pointed out in the comments, if all you're doing is adding elements to the list, then the most general type you can have is not `List<Event>` but `List<? super Event>`, since you could feasibly pass a list of any supertype of `Event` and your method would still work correctly. Some care must be taken, as using `? super Event` could cause some issues trying to access list elements later, but if all you're doing in the method is *writing to* the list, then it works perfectly.

Comment: Actually, he wants `List<? super Foo>`, so a `List<Object>` would be fine too.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I edited the question just a minute ago to be more precise about my problem. Thus his answer may seem too complex at first.